# Is there a function for integer fmod in C++?

Tags: c++, modular-arithmetic, modulo

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod

Alright, cool. There's this function called `fmod`, but it appears to only work with `float`, `double`, and `long double`. Is there a version of this function that works with integers in C++?

Comment: Do you mean the modulus `%` operator?

Comment: IMHO `fmodX()` is port of more primary `%` concept to floating point (BTW unnatural )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, '%' is used for modulus operator, as Joducus said in the comment.  See [example](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html).

Comment: Pumping of reputation?

Comment: @JacekCz Despicable isn't it? I'll get the pitchforks.

Comment: So why can't the operator work for floats if there's already an operator in the language?